# Modify packet's payload in pcap

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, pcap, packet-capture, tshark

So I have to generate some specific pcap files with one packet in each. I have followings options:

1) I can modify the payload of an existing pcap file that I have (I'm not successful in this even after spending hours googling about it. Headers can be edited but couldn't find any resource claiming payload modifications)

2) I can create a new pcap which contains payload of my choice (for ex. Packet must contain one specific string )

Which of the above is feasible and can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using wireshark's [text2pcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html). It can create pcap files from ASCII text in hex.

Dump an existing packet to ASCII, edit the text, then generate your pcap file.